# Dynamic Validation message in Constraint Validation of Enums

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller, hibernate-validator, javax-validation, jakarta-validation

I was trying to Validate the Enum before Request Processing,

**EnumValidator.java**

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface EnumValidator {

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

    String message() default "value not valid {enumClass}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**EnumValidatorImpl.java**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EnumValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, Enum<?>> {

    private List<String> allowableValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        allowableValues = Stream.of(constraintAnnotation.enumClass()
                .getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Enum<?> anEnum, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return anEnum != null && allowableValues.contains(anEnum.name());
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Person {

    @EnumValidator(enumClass = Status.class)
    private String status;
}
```

**Status.java**

```
public enum Status {

    ACTIVE,
    IN_ACTIVE
}
```

It was working fine in-terms of validation, Right now the message comes as **value not valid emumclass** package name. Is there any to display all the members of enum in error message in this case ACTIVE, IN_ACTIVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the Hibernate Validator you can cast the context in the validator to `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext`, and that would allow you to add additional message parameters:

```java
public class EnumValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, Enum<?>> {

    private List<String> allowableValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        allowableValues = Stream.of(constraintAnnotation.enumClass()
                        .getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Enum<?> anEnum, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if ( constraintValidatorContext instanceof HibernateConstraintValidatorContext ) {
            ( (HibernateConstraintValidatorContext) constraintValidatorContext ).addMessageParameter(
                    "enumConstants", allowableValues );
        }
        return anEnum != null && allowableValues.contains(anEnum.name());
    }
}
```

and then use these message parameters in the message template:

```java
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface EnumValidator {

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

    String message() default "value not valid {enumClass}. Available options: {enumConstants}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```